# Img is overflowing top-menu

Tags: html, css

My img is overflowing a block higher(my menu) while i add a blur filter. How to fix this?

when i delete the blur filter everything is fine, and its not overflowing top-menu.

I also was trying to use z-index, but id didn`t help. I also tried all the internet solutions like adding to a parent "position:relative;" but nothing works

the top menu:

```css
.dws-menu{
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-color: white;
 height: 8%;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
ul.dws-ul{
 display: flex;
 padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
 justify-content: center;

 font-weight: 700;
}
li.dws-li{
    margin-top: 10px;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 10px;
}
li.dws-li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #000;
 position: relative;
 padding: 5px;
}
li.dws-li a i{
 margin-right: 10px;
}
li.dws-li a::before{
 content: '';
 width: 0;
 height: 3px;
 background-color: #33bdf1;
 position: absolute;
 top: 90%;
 left: 0;
 transition: .5s;
 mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
li.dws-li a::after{
 content: '';
 width: 0;
 height: 3px;
 background-color: #ff2117;
 position: absolute;
 top: 90%;
 right: 0;
 transition: .5s;
 mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
li.dws-li:hover{
 background-color: #e5eae8;
}
li.dws-li:hover a::before{
 width: 50%;
 transform: translateX(100%);
}
li.dws-li:hover a::after{
 width: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-100%);
}
li.dws-li a:hover{
 color: #e62117;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="dws-menu">
        <ul class="dws-ul">
            <li class="dws-li"><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Main</a></li>
            <li class="dws-li"><a href="basketbal.html"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Basketbal</a></li>
            <img class="img2" src="img/1075154.png" alt="Картинка"> 
            <li class="dws-li"><a href="aboutme.html"><i class="fa fa-server" aria-hidden="true"></i>Personalia</a></li>

            <li class="dws-li"><a href="school.html"><i class="fa fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></i>School</a></li>
            <li class="dws-li"><a href="skills.html"><i class="fa fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></i>Skills</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

```css
.basketbalbg{
    
}
.basketbalphoto{
 display: flex;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 filter: blur(8px);
}
```

```html
<div class="basketbalbg ">
    <img class="basketbalphoto" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Картинка"></img>
</div>
```

Whole code:

```css
.bgspiska{
    background: url('../img/5594016.jpg') 50% repeat;
    border: 10px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 5px #000000;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-radius: 30px;

}
.under{
    margin-top: 100px ;
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-top: 5px solid #383838;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.basketbalbg{
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.basketbalphoto{
 display: flex;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 filter: blur(8px);

}
.basketbaltext{
        line-height: 1.7;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 150px;
    color: black;
    font-family: PointBold;
    font-size: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px lightgrey, 0 0 1em lightgrey, 0 0 0.2em lightgrey;
}
.dws-menu{
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-color: white;
 height: 8%;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
ul.dws-ul{
 display: flex;
 padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
 justify-content: center;

 font-weight: 700;
}
li.dws-li{
    margin-top: 10px;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 10px;
}
li.dws-li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #000;
 position: relative;
 padding: 5px;
}
li.dws-li a i{
 margin-right: 10px;
}
li.dws-li a::before{
 content: '';
 width: 0;
 height: 3px;
 background-color: #33bdf1;
 position: absolute;
 top: 90%;
 left: 0;
 transition: .5s;
 mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
li.dws-li a::after{
 content: '';
 width: 0;
 height: 3px;
 background-color: #ff2117;
 position: absolute;
 top: 90%;
 right: 0;
 transition: .5s;
 mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
li.dws-li:hover{
 background-color: #e5eae8;
}
li.dws-li:hover a::before{
 width: 50%;
 transform: translateX(100%);
}
li.dws-li:hover a::after{
 width: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-100%);
}
li.dws-li a:hover{
 color: #e62117;
}
```

```html
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/photo.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Maksym Gurko</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="dws-menu">
        <ul class="dws-ul">
            <li class="dws-li"><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Main</a></li>
            <li class="dws-li"><a href="basketbal.html"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Basketbal</a></li>
            <img class="img2" src="img/1075154.png" alt="Картинка"> 
            <li class="dws-li"><a href="aboutme.html"><i class="fa fa-server" aria-hidden="true"></i>Personalia</a></li>

            <li class="dws-li"><a href="school.html"><i class="fa fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></i>School</a></li>
            <li class="dws-li"><a href="skills.html"><i class="fa fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></i>Skills</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="basketbalbg ">
    <img
 class="basketbalphoto" src="img/basketbalphoto.jpg" alt="Картинка">
    </img>
</div>

<div class="bgspiska">
    <p class="basketbaltext">My highlights</p>
    </div>

   <div class="under">
    <span>© Maksym Gurko</span>
   </div>
</body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please add enough code to create a [mre] - Furthermore the `img`-element has no closing tag `</img>`

Comment: its there: <div class="basketbalbg ">
    <img class="basketbalphoto" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Картинка"></img>
</div>

Comment: "*My img is overflowing a block higher(my menu)*" - ... where is the menu?

Comment: added it to the post, sorry

Comment: the image starts to overflow after i add the blur filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to give margin or padding to basketbalbg wrapper because dws-menu is on fixed position so you need to give same spacing from top to the next element of header and it does not depend on blur effect.

```css
header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.basketbalbg{
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
  .basketbalphoto{
   display: flex;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   filter: blur(8px);
  }
  .dws-menu{
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
ul.dws-ul{
 display: flex;
 padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
 justify-content: center;

 font-weight: 700;
}
li.dws-li{
    margin-top: 10px;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 10px;
}
li.dws-li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #000;
 position: relative;
 padding: 5px;
}
li.dws-li a i{
 margin-right: 10px;
}
li.dws-li a::before{
 content: '';
 width: 0;
 height: 3px;
 background-color: #33bdf1;
 position: absolute;
 top: 90%;
 left: 0;
 transition: .5s;
 mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
li.dws-li a::after{
 content: '';
 width: 0;
 height: 3px;
 background-color: #ff2117;
 position: absolute;
 top: 90%;
 right: 0;
 transition: .5s;
 mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
li.dws-li:hover{
 background-color: #e5eae8;
}
li.dws-li:hover a::before{
 width: 50%;
 transform: translateX(100%);
}
li.dws-li:hover a::after{
 width: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-100%);
}
li.dws-li a:hover{
 color: #e62117;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Horizontal Scrollbar Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main-wrp">
    <header>
      <div class="dws-menu">
          <ul class="dws-ul">
              <li class="dws-li"><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Main</a></li>
              <li class="dws-li"><a href="basketbal.html"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Basketbal</a></li>
              <img class="img2" src="img/1075154.png" alt="Картинка"> 
              <li class="dws-li"><a href="aboutme.html"><i class="fa fa-server" aria-hidden="true"></i>Personalia</a></li>
  
              <li class="dws-li"><a href="school.html"><i class="fa fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></i>School</a></li>
              <li class="dws-li"><a href="skills.html"><i class="fa fa-bookmark" aria-hidden="true"></i>Skills</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </header>
  <div class="basketbalbg">
    <img class="basketbalphoto" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="Картинка"></img>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if this works for you or not.

Comment: didn`t help, still the same, hovering the top menu

Comment: and if i delete the blur filter everything is fine

Comment: You have shared 2 different code snipped. Can you combine both so I can see how it's actually working at your end ?

Comment: did it, but it doesnt have pictures so u cant actually see..

Comment: Now, fixed please check @максимгурко